# Downloaded Stanford eclipse and do not know how to run

Tags: eclipse

Heello, I downloaded eclipse.zip from Stanford website(I need it for CS106a class) and do not know how to run after unzipping, please help.

Link: http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106a/cs106a.1166/eclipse.shtml

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the eclipse-linux64.zip archive that you downloaded.
2. Extract the contents of the archive:

   ```
   unzip eclipse-linux64.zip
   ```
3. Change directories to the eclipse folder.

   ```
   cd eclipse
   ```
4. Start Eclipse.

   ```
   ./eclipse
   ```

Comment: I just run stanford eclipse-x64 with  terminal ./eclipse command, and trying to "install new software" from  https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/eclipse/plugin I can see slight difference in interface... I'm to noob to know what is the real difference between them(maybe there is not at all xD ). Thank you so much, that was my first question on askubuntu.  ^_^